# Alter GTK2 style (only) in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: themes, gtk

I know there's Qt5ct for tweaking the look of QT apps in Ubuntu, but I have a couple apps I use a lot (like gmusicbrowser) which are only stable in a gtk2 version.

In the case of gmusicbrowser, the space around words in tabs is too narrow, and the contrast between colors is too slight for things like highlighting alternating rows. I want to tweak the GTK2 style, or change its theme, without altering anything else. How do I do this?

Comment: Same problem here, with HexChat...